# Embed a React component in a text area, and then parse it?

Tags: reactjs

Is is possible to include a React component call within a block of text and then get React to execute the component?

For example, let's say I had:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id libero rutrum, volutpat nisi non, tempus ipsum. <InsertStuff props={props} /> Vestibulum vel sapien lacus. Pellentesque tristique erat a purus tempus, vitae vulputate nulla consequat`

I'd like React to see `<InsertStuff props={props} />` and execute the component so that I get:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id libero rutrum, volutpat nisi non, tempus ipsum. HERE'S THE STUFF GENERATED BY THE COMPONENT Vestibulum vel sapien lacus. Pellentesque tristique erat a purus tempus, vitae vulputate nulla consequat`

Can this be done?

Comment: This can certainly be done, as long as the text is within a JSX block. In any case I'd suggest trying it first, then asking about any issues you encounter instead.

Comment: Keep in mind React doesn't really "execute" components, it *mounts and begins rendering* them.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done - in your `render()` method (or in the return value if using a functional component) you need to guarantee that there is a top level tag, even if it renders nothing (e.g. `<></>` or `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`)

More info

- [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)
- [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Live example that does not add any new tags (div/span/etc) to the DOM - will print:

`<div id="root">Inline text before a component with props: {"randomProp":"value"} and some text after</div>`

```js
const Component = (props) => (
  <React.Fragment>
  a component with props: {JSON.stringify(props)}
  </React.Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
     Inline text before <Component randomProp="value"/> and some text after
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Will this work if you are pulling in the text (including the component call) from a database? I'm using Strapi, and would like to be able to store the text in the database and then parse it for the component when I render it.

Comment: I've added component call to a textarea, in Strapi, but when it renders it is simply showing me the text with <Component />. It doesn't mount or render the component.

I've tried using the ReactHtmlParser, but this doesn't do anything (which probably isn't that surprising)

Comment: not sure about your specific problem - it doesn't matter if it's coming from a database - but perhaps if you provide more code it will be easier